# CSS Justify text, fill space with dots

Tags: css, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fill available spaces between labels with dots or hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097851/fill-available-spaces-between-labels-with-dots-or-hyphens)

Any way to format text like this with simple CSS? I have a DB of different products with their drugs and doses and want to display them uniformly, but without monospaced fonts.

```
Drug 1 ............  10ml
Another drug ......  50ml
Third ............. 100ml
```

Comment: Interesting question, never seen this done in HTML. Do the dots `.` need to be dots or could they come from a background image as well?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this can be done using pure HTML and CSS, theoretically even without a background image. Can you work with fixed widths, or does the whole thing need to be dynamic e.g. when resizing the page?

Comment: using tables and border is a fair approach i would say http://jsfiddle.net/PAQzW/1/

Comment: See this [http://jsfiddle.net/GrAxb/][1]

Borrowed the code from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097851/fill-available-spaces-between-labels-with-dots-or-hyphens][2], and adjusted it a bit


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/GrAxb/
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097851/fill-available-spaces-between-labels-with-dots-or-hyphens

Comment: it seems a bad idea to complicate things like that just for dots, but this is what he wanted. +1

Comment: Searched for 5 minutes and didn't find that post. It works great for what I'm trying to do, thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here's an elegant and unobtrusive one with some limitations (see below).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6JWT/7/)

CSS:

```
dl { width: 400px }
dt { float: left; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap }
dd { float: left; width: 100px; overflow: hidden }

dt:after { content: " .................................................................................." }
```

HTML:

```
<dl>

    <dt>Drug 1</dt>
    <dd>10ml</dd>

    <dt>Another drug</dt>
    <dd>50ml</dd>

    <dt>Third</dt>
    <dd>100ml</dd>


</dl>
```

limitations:

- Doesn't work in IE < 8
- Accepts only literal characters in the `content` property, no HTML entities, so no `&middot;` for example. (This is no problem as @Radek points out, as UTF-8 characters should be able to serve almost every need here).

Comment: Are HTML entities a problem? We have Unicode these days, and web pages should be UTF-8.

Comment: @Radek true, good point. I don't have much experience with `content:` and wasn't sure what it accepts. A quick test shows that Unicode characters are no problem, updated.

Comment: @Pekka It also works without those SPAN elements: http://jsfiddle.net/j6JWT/76/

Comment: here is another example https://jsfiddle.net/s6yfaeLp/

Answer (score 6):

Another method:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbbUD/2/)**

```
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
}
td span {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
td.name:before {
    clip: rect(0px, 190px, 20px, 0px);
    content: " ............................................................ ";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
td.amt {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><span>Drug 1</span></td>
        <td class="amt"><span>10mL</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><span>Another drug</span></td>
        <td class="amt"><span>50mL</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><span>Third</span></td>
        <td class="amt"><span>100mL</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Similar restrictions as Pekka's solution, and would require updating the `clip()` coords if the width of the table changed.

Comment: I think your solution looks great in the jsfiddle, but I had a hard time implementing it in an existing design, mainly because of the z-index. Anyway +1.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can use css to format divs in order to get that structure. Example:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="prods">
Drug 1
Another drug
Third
</div>
<div class="dims">
10ml
50ml
100ml
</div>
</div>
```

Then you format it css:

```
.prods{float: left; width: 100px}
.dims{float: left; width: 35px}
```

This is just a very simple example just to get that structure, you should add more visual detail of course.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's main issue: To fill the space with dots.  Also, since he's displaying tabular data, `<div>`s are unnecessary here.

Comment: Yes, when i first saw the dots i didn't knew that he really wanted dots, i thought that it was just to show the alignment, and we can use divs to display tabular data instead of tables, why not?

Comment: @Leandro: Your layout is not semantic and would be very confusing for someone using a screen reader or other accessibility tool.