# CSS: Text-line-icon. Set the line to auto-increase width depends on text length?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do this:

[image]

into html so when I type some text the line gets longer or shorter.
On the end of each line there is a small icon of height of 32px so I would image each line would be `line-height:32px`.

Shall I use `<li>` or div's and sort the icon next to the line next to the text with float:left? And how would the line increase it self? I would imagine the line would have a background-color and a height of 1px?

I'm not new to CSS, I'm just trying to think of the simplest way of doing this. Note that each line is a button which expands.

Thanks alot

Edit:

It will actually look something like this:
[image]

Each div is a toggle button and I would like the grey line to be in the middle of the entire div if that makes sense.

Thanks alot again

Comment: tried something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476673/css-justify-text-fill-space-with-dots

Comment: It is not cross-browser compatible. Thank though

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? IE7? IE8?

Comment: IE7+ and all other major browsers sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is to use border-bottom on the text container, then push the text out with negative bottom.

Quite simple really, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfreak/DCZSa/

Comment: Thanks. I think there is a better way to show you what I'm aiming for which will make it easier for you to think of an alternative way. The <li> I believe it is not a solution since I haven't got many options. One minute I'm updating my question with a new image.

Comment: @jQuerybeast Updated jsfiddle with icons. The <li> is really not a requirement. You can use whatever tag you like

Comment: Oops, the fiddle URL has changed

Comment: The way you've did it, I would image that there would be few problems with the content of each <li>. Can you please check the update sir on the new upload pic? Thanks alot for your help. I am having a look at your updated fiddle.

Comment: @jQuerybeast Sure thing, check updated fiddle. Adding 'active' class to the `<li>` will reveal the text

Comment: @jQuerybeast Added JS to expand/collapse just for kicks! :)

Comment: Haha... I message you a final piece then :)

Answer (score 0):

If your background is solid, I would probably implement this like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/JLwwP/

First, use an all-white background (or whatever color).  Then, on your list items, tile your horizontal line.  Then, float the image (with a white background) to the right.  Finally, wrap your left-hand text in a span and make it's background the same solid.

It's not perfect (it requires some fiddling with node heights to make everything work), but you can see the effect.

Comment: How would I make the li { background-color: #F0F0FF; a line of 1px height? They way you've did it, doesn't allow me to change the height of the line and have it in the middle.

Comment: Don't use the background-color on the LI - use a repeating background image.

Comment: I see what you mean. That was my first thought actually. I asked this question for that reason, on how to prevent images. Thanks alot sir