# how to style in css: product...(price)?

Tags: html, css

Hard for me to explain what I'm trying to achieve in a question. I've actually built it in a fiddle, but I know theirs got to be a smarter way of doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/4QgtM/1/

### What I'm trying to achieve

```
Car ............................... $2000
Boat ............................. $20000
Airplane ........................ $200000
```

### What I've got (Hack)

```
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Car</a><i></i><span>$2000</span></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Boat</a><i></i><span>$20000</span></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Airplane</a><i></i><span>$200000</span></li>
```

Does anyone have a smart way of achieving this? thanks!

Comment: Check this out, maybe it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476673/css-justify-text-fill-space-with-dots

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out... (inspired by [this](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html))

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mHZt8/)**

CSS:

```
ul.leaders {
    max-width: 40em;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    list-style: none
}
ul.leaders li:before {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
}
ul.leaders span:first-child {
    padding-right: 0.33em;
    background: white
}
ul.leaders span + span {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 0.33em;
    background: white
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class=leaders>
    <li><span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Car</a></span>
    <span>$200</span>

    <li><span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Boat</a></span>
    <span>$2000</span>

    <li><span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Airplane</a></span>
    <span>$20000</span>

    <li><span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Hover craft</a></span>
    <span>$200000</span>

    <li><span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Supersonic futuristic machine</a></span>
    <span>$2000000</span>
</ul>
```

**"Just for the record" :**
- another solution is to have a small dot in a img/png as background. (`background: #FFF url(image.pn) repeat-x;`
- one more solution is to have `border-bottom: dotted;`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4QgtM/5/

try this

```
i {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted;

    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 2px 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 15px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    z-index: 0;
}
```