# Table of Contents with dotted underline in html

Tags: html, css, tableofcontents

I'm trying to create a table of contents in html in the form of

```
Introduction.................................1
Heading 1....................................1
Heading 2....................................2
```

Now I'd like the ... to go from the last character in the title to the number of the right.

I can get this working sort of in a table with a single tr and two tds (one for the title and one for the page number) with a border-bottom on the first td, however the .. goes across the entire border instead of just from the last character.

Is there a better way I can represent this in html?

As to why I'm doing this in HTML we are exporting it to a HTML-> PDF converter so it has to be HTML.

This is what I have so far

```
<h1>Contents</h1>

<ul>
    <li>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr style="">
                <td>System Overview Manual..adn the dog went to the zoo and had a really good time and it was really really good.</td>
                <td style="text-align: right; "> <span id='contents1'>2</span>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EBhAX/

Comment: You could add a center `td`. Give all the `td`s fixed percentage and use `border-bottom` on the second `td`. However, what about indented TOC contents like in chapter 1, there is 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2 etc.

Comment: Just for give my opinion, I like your version very much than the deserved one, I think is easier to see what chapter matchs with the page, particulary if there will be a lot of contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use generated content for the dots... (I learned this from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312503/how-to-style-in-css-product-price))

> We create the dot leaders with a ‘:before’ pseudo-element attached to
>   the LI elements. The pseudo-element fills the whole width of the list
>   item with dots and the SPANs are put on top. A white background on the
>   SPANs hides the dots behind them and an ‘overflow: hidden’ on the UL
>   ensures the dots do not extend outside the list: (from [this w3.org article](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html))

**EDIT:** Updated code to allow for nested lists

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/WTnma/3/)**

### Markup

```
<ul class="outer">
    <li><a href="#">Introduction</a><span>1</span></li>
    <li class="nested">
        <ul class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Header 1</a><span>2</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Header 2</a><span>2</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Header 2</a><span>3</span></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.outer {
    width: 70%;  
}
.inner
{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
li:not(.nested):before {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
}
li a:first-child {
    padding-right: 0.33em;
    background: white
}
a + span {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 0.33em;
    background: white
}
```

Comment: This looks good, one thing how would I make all sub lists have their numbers appear in the same position as the top ones, http://jsfiddle.net/WTnma/2/

Comment: that looks awesome, even works for further indented lists, will try this at work tomrrow and if its all good will mark this as the answer

Comment: Unfortunately the pdf software I'm using wont identify the pseduo elements correct so I can process them so I can't use this approach, however for straight HTML i think this is the best so I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `border-bottom` on the middle td with a class:

```
td.text {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EBhAX/2/

Comment: Ha, I just added comment with similar answer. However, your fiddle link does not work.

Comment: It gives the same output as OP's fiddle. Plus there is no middle `td` like you said.

Comment: introduction and system overview manual would be 2 separate headings but they are both on the same line here

Answer (score 0):

See this Fiddle.

**http://jsfiddle.net/EBhAX/4/**

You can add one more td in middle & give the css to that td with border-bottom. give the css "width in percent" to all the td.

Try this It will be helpful.

Comment: that works fine as long as the text is long enough but for something short you still get a blank section http://jsfiddle.net/EBhAX/5/

Comment: td:first-child {
    min-width:35%;
}

td.border {
    width:60%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
change the width of td. & give the min-width of 1st td