# make dots after text with auto size

Tags: html, css

Need want to automatically make a point after the text

for example

```
hellow world ................ 5

hellow ...................... 6

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy 
text of the printing ........ 7


<div style="width:150px"> hellow world </div> <div style="float:right">6</div>

<div style="width:150px"> hellow </div> <div style="float:right">6</div>

<div style="width:150px"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing </div> <div style="float:right">6</div>
```

Comment: or [CSS Justify text, fill space with dots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476673/css-justify-text-fill-space-with-dots) or several others

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I can find is this article: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html

Should get you on the right track :-)

There's also a new CSS3 technique for it: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#leaders but I can't find any browser support references.

Comment: Weird, somebody deleted all the comments to this, even mine.