# Fill in empty space with dots

Tags: css, xhtml, doctype

I'm trying to get the same result as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476673/css-justify-text-fill-space-with-dots), but unable to. I would add a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Here's my current code.

```css
dl {
  width: 400px
}

dt {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}

dd {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden
}

dt:after {
  content: " .................................................................................."
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">

<dl>

  <dt>Drug 1</dt>
  <dd>10ml</dd>

  <dt>Another drug</dt>
  <dd>50ml</dd>

  <dt>Third</dt>
  <dd>100ml</dd>
  
</dl>

</html>
```

When I try HTML5, `<!DOCTYPE html><html>`, it doesn't work at all!

What code will work with the following `DOCTYPE`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Comment: The first doctype you show is the current one for all new web pages and is required. The second one you show is for XHTML only. You shouldn't be using the second one because I'm sure you aren't serving XHTML despite the XML prologue in your markup. What you show is a mish-mash of markup that is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

You need to:

- wrap each of them sections with `dl`
- add the CSS`dd {  margin: 0  }`

```css
dd {  margin: 0  }

dl {
  width: 400px
}

dt {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}

dd {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden
}

dt:after {
  content: " .................................................................................."
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Drug 1</dt>
  <dd>10ml</dd>
</dl>

<dl>
  <dt>Another drug</dt>
  <dd>50ml</dd>
</dl>

<dl>
  <dt>Third</dt>
  <dd>100ml</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Oh god!...
Now this fail when I try create my page INDEX using DOMPDF :'(

Any idea please?

Comment: Sorry @Stackoverflow I did not see your message until now. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Thanks by your interesting, that was a work for university, I leave that now... :-) is possible contact a user (email, PM) in StackOverflow.com?

Comment: @Stackoverflow You could create a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new