# Add content after, but hide once it reaches next element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox and several divs inside, which should be justified as `space-around`. On the screenshot you can see that this is a part of table of contents of a book, but the problem is that because this is flexbox and because screens have different sizes, space between dots isn't constant.

[image: example]

My idea is to fill it with content after, so for example:

```
<div class="myflexbox">
  <div class="dot">.</div>
  <div class="dot">.</div>
  <div class="dot">.</div>
  <div class="pagenumber">.1160</div>
</div>
```

we will have something like this in styles for content after:

```
.dot:after {
  content: "..................."; //millions of dots
}
```

Is there a way to hide extra dots so it doesn't overlap once content after reaches next dot or page number?

Comment: We need to see a _working code snippet reproduce the issue_, not just a fragment.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476673/css-justify-text-fill-space-with-dots

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept? ... or it simply didn't work?

Comment: Since I didn't got any response I deleted my answer.