# Give border bottom on the second div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I have two DIV-s, which must fill the space of their upper div. Size of the first div can differ - depends on the text inside the div. What I want is to show dots to the end of remaining space.

My solution:

```css
.drugi {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>this is testing</div>
  <div class="drugi"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is output:

[image]

Dots are occupying the whole space. What I would like it to be is this:

[image]

Please note: I've already tried solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476673/css-justify-text-fill-space-with-dots) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097851/fill-available-spaces-between-labels-with-dots-or-hyphens). My question differs, because I don't have fixed width of either DIV-s, so second DIV must simply fill remaining space with dots, without overlapping the first DIV.

Comment: Read about [css Ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: Ellipsis add three dots at the end, which is not what I am looking for. I want to fill the whole remaining space with dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Flex`

```css
.outer{
display:flex;
}
.drugi{
  border-bottom:1px dashed black;   
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>this is testing this is testing</div>
  <div class="drugi"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using: flex:1 ?

Comment: `Why are you using: flex:1` reaming with cover

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox`.

```css
.drugi{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    flex: auto; 
}
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div>this is testing</div>
  <div class="drugi"></div>  
</div>


<div class="d-flex">
  <div>this is</div>
  <div class="drugi"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

HTML:

```
<div class="Table">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="Table_title">this is testing</div>
       <div class="Table_border"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Table .row {
  display: table;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.Table_title{
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.Table_border{
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```